# Why this PHP code does not run - Code fitter Mail

Tags: php, file, readfile

I have code

```
require_once('verify.php');

$file = 'mail.txt';
$allfile = file($file);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $cuong = $allfile[$i];
    $dep = 'admin@ngocuong.net';
    $kq = verifyEmail($cuong, $dep);
    if($kq == '2') {
        echo 'OK<br />';
    } else {
        echo 'Nope<br />';
    }
}
echo 'Done!!!';
```

with `$cuong = 'cuong.fl310@gmail.com';` code run. Return is OK.
But i put all my list email into file mail.txt. And run code read line in file txt. `$cuong = $allfile[$i]` code not run. 
I had show

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 $cuong = $allfile[$i]
 echo $cuong;
}
```

it print list email in file txt. With `$i= 0; $cuong = 'cuong.fl310@gmail.com'` But code not run. Return enqual: Nope !!!

Plz help me fix it.

Thanks for readding!!!

Comment: Any errors in your logs ?

Comment: First of all: You should consider using foreach when iterating over an array (or make sure that the array really has 11 elements). You should also consider passing `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` to the file function as 2nd argument as your array might contain empty elements and line ends as part of the email. Also enable error_reporting and display_errors and post all messages.

Comment: Whats the error message shown? Post the source code for the function *verifyEmail()*